# Type Checker: Declaration for `n' provided, but `n' has no definition in: n

Tags: scheme, racket, typed-racket

i am trying to do factorial calculator function in Lisp/drRacket but i got problems and cant figure out.

[image]

```html
#lang typed/racket
(: n Number)
(define (faktoriyel n)
    (cond
        ((< n 0) (error "eksi sayıların faktoriyeli olmaz"))
        ((and (>= n 0) (<= n 1)) 1)
        (else (* n (faktoriyel (- n 1))))))
```

Comment: The type declaration needs to be in the function. You're providing a type declaration for a global variable, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Where i can declare it exactly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be declaring the type of the function, not the variable `n`:

```
(: faktoriyel (-> Number Number))
```

`(-> Number Number)` means a function that takes a `Number` as a parameter and returns a `Number`.

See [Function Types](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/types.html#%28part._.Function_.Types%29) in the documentation.